# Is there anyway to hide / obfuscate .realm files on android?

Tags: android, android-file, android-security, realm

I'm planning to store hashed passwords and PINs using realm. I've been researching on salting, and it's recommended to have a different salt for each password / PIN. Also it's recommended that the salt should be somewhere within the database.

My question is are .realm files secure? Is there a way to guarantee that the contents of the .realm files cannot be opened?

Comment: security using obscurity is not security, Its a very basic concept in security however you have to encrypt your realm file which provides encryption and generate the keys in a secure manner i.e. by using the android keystore api

Answer (score 2):

In general you can get the the realm file from the phone (if it rooted) and read it via realm browser (https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx). But there are possibility to encrypt the *.realm file. Look at the corresponding section of the documentation https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#encryption .

Answer (score 0):

Realm files aren't encrypted by default, however realm does support encryption of the files.

You can view the encryption documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#encryption), and an example implementation [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/encryptionExample).

You should also read up on the Android [keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html), which will allow you to securely store the key.